# Окончание глагола

Tags: синтаксис, согласование, глаголы, сказуемые

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно:

Чем меньше полок, тем меньше ненужных вещей **будУТ** храниться дома

*или*

Чем меньше полок, тем меньше ненужных вещей **будЕТ** храниться дома?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Чем меньше полок, тем меньше ненужных вещей будет храниться дома.

Если в состав подлежащего входит слово с неопределенным значением (много, немного, мало, несколько), то сказуемое обычно ставится в единственном числе (из "Практической стилистики современного языка").

Comment: А где здесь подлежащее?

Comment: Бельчиковым увлекаетесь? В принципе ничего крамольного он в вашей цитате не сказал, но поразителен сам выбор источника.

Comment: Если Бельчиков - ненадежный источник, можно сослаться на Розенталя (информация от этого не изменится, всё один к одному). Кстати (по Розенталю) в Грамматике  52  говорится, что множественное число  сказуемого при наличии слов  "много, немного, мало, несколько" имеет просторечный характер (мне и сейчас так кажется). С другой стороны, язык развивается, надо пользоваться современной литературой (а Бельчиков всё-таки рекомендован  РАН, 2012 год). Или Вы можете посоветовать другой справочник по стилистике (авторитетный, современный)?

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, возможны оба варианта, но с *будет* - лучше.

На Грамоте.ру есть ответ на похожий вопрос: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer/?s=289955

P. S. Возможно, стоит переформулировать предложение, так как в нынешнем виде в нем есть тавтология: *чем **меньше**, тем **меньше***.